# webView height constraint based on dynamic content

Tags: ios, swift, webview, constraints

I have an embedded webView at the bottom of a screen, which loads the Facebook comments javascript plugin.

I want this webView to be seamlessly integrated in the screen, without forcing the user to scroll its contents.

However, when the user taps on some of the webView buttons, the UI height changes, making the webView scrollable.

### Question

How do I dynamically update the webView height constraint based on its dynamic contents?

Comment: I don't have much experience with the issue you're facing, but you can drag constraints from a storyboard to your viewController and tweak them programatically. You might want to take a peek at this if you haven't already. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/add_constraints-control_drag.html

Comment: Based on the webView's content? I really don't see how you could. Perhaps it's possible by injecting / receiving javascript from the webView. Good luck

Comment: @AdrianB I already tried tying the webView height constraint –both from the storyboard and even programmatically– to the webView scrollView height, with no luck.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu yes to the content. I could easily do this with a timer that checks for changes in the 2 heights and in case adjusts them accordingly, but then I wouldn't sleep at night for having done something like that. I was looking to exploit the event that triggers the height change in the webView's scrollView (it must trigger since I am always able to scroll the whole page after the page changes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Set height constraint for you web view in storyboard and then inside webviewDidFinishLoad do following

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled=false;
heightConstraint.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
```

Where `heightConstraint` is IBOutlet of web view's height constraint. Call setNeedsLayout() after modifying constraint if needed. Also make sure that bottom constraint for web view is set equal to bottom of scroll view so that it expands freely.

**UPDATE**
You can add key value observer for contentSize for your webview's scroll view. You can do it in this way

```
var myContext = 0
webView.scrollView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .New, context: &myContext) 
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if context == &myContext {
        heightConstraint.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        //call layout update if needed
    } else {
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}
```

Comment: Something I found working similar requirement, was that you must set your webview's height constraint to at least '1' initially, in your storyboard. If you give it a value of zero initially, it doesn't updates its value when you set it using contentSize.height

Just added so that it can help someone not waste their time.